# Make a Range in VBA that spans sheets?

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to make a Range that spans several sheets, a 3-D Reference as they call it. [Here is MS's example](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Create-a-3-D-reference-to-the-same-cell-range-on-multiple-worksheets-40ca91ff-9dcb-4ad1-99d2-787d0bc888b6) of how to do it manually. Well I need to do it in code (no, I can't use a sheet formula). So I did...

```
Set m1 = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(1, 1)
Set m2 = Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(3, 1)
Set m3 = Union(m1, m2)
```

However, this returns the dreaded '1004' error, as does every other syntax I've tried. Then I tried just doing this manually by shift-selecting multiple sheets and using this...

```
Private Sub Workbook_SheetSelectionChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)
    MsgBox "range address: " & Target.Address
End Sub
```

And that *always* returns only the part of the selection on the ActiveSheet.

So, is there any way to make a Range that spans sheets?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A `Range` object can only be a set of cells on a single worksheet.  However you can create an **array** of  ranges or a **collection** of ranges that can span more than one worksheet.

Comment: Ok, that is an answer even if its not the one I wanted :-) I am surprised to hear this, but I will use the collection method.